# Delete one element of data from column

Tags: sql, entity-framework

[SQL data]

[image: 1]

I'm trying to remove just a specific data from the answerfile row within a chosen answerId.

```
 {
     var myInv = _context.Answer.SingleOrDefault(m => m.AnswerId == PersonIdClass.answerid);

        if (myInv!=null)
        {
            _context.Answer.Remove(myInv);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

 }
```

The personIdClass is a class i made to get the right answerId value. The problem is that i am removing a the whole row, and not the specific data on the given chosen row. Should i try to change MyInv to a IList instead?

Example with table:

| ID | Course | Answerfile |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | math | xxxx |
| 2 | Physics | xxxx |

Now I'm trying to delete the specific data from the answerfile where the ID is = 1.

---

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What is "a specific data from the answerfile row"? Do mean that you want to update the row instead of deleting it? Also, please post text, not images.

Comment: i'm not understand the problem too. But i think to may to want just update row with change data in some column ?

Comment: Don't use `Remove` - that deletes the record. Just clear the column: `myInv.AnswerFile = null;` - then SaveChanges();